# Is it possible to serve Brotli compressed files from Firebase Storage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, gzip, firebase-storage, brotli

If I upload a file on Firebase Storage as Gzip and Brotli compressed, would it be possible  to serve the right file based on input headers from the client browser ?

Thanks, Julien

Answer (score 3):

Cloud Storage for Firebase serves static files purely based on the URL of the request. There is no support for any other deciding factors to determine the file to serve for a request.

This means that Cloud Storage for Firebase can definitely serve Brotli files. But it can't itself choose to serve either a Brotli file or  GZIP file for the same URL.

It's an interesting idea though, so I'd [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).